# Proof that $\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{(-1)^k}{k+1} {n \choose k} = \frac{1}{n+1}$ for every $n \in N$.

Tags: binomial-coefficients

I want to show that $$ \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{(-1)^k}{k+1} {n \choose k} = \frac{1}{n+1} $$
I know, that I will have to use that for $ l \geq 1 $ $$ \sum_{i=0}^l (-1)^i {l \choose i} = 0 $$.
My idea is that I write: $$ \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{(-1)^k}{k+1} {n \choose k} = \sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k {n \choose k} \frac{1}{k+1}$$ but in order to continue with my proof I know that I have to pull out a constant from the sum because I'm pretty sure the last step of the proof ought to be using the second "sum-rule" to make it 0 and there will be only $ \frac{1}{n+1}$ left.

Summary: my problem is that I don't know how to get to that second line (beginning at "..that for $l\geq1$") because there is a l and i and in my last line there is a n and a k.

Furthermore I don't know how to get that "k+1" to become "n+1" and whether I can just pull it out of the sum since it isn't a constant but dependent upon the k, which is running towards n.

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/994108/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3025512/42969 – found with [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Csum_%7Bk%3D0%7D%5En%20%5Cfrac%7B(-1)%5Ek%7D%7Bk%2B1%7D%20%7Bn%20%5Cchoose%20k%7D%20%3D%20%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7Bn%2B1%7D%24)

Comment: Another one (found in the “Related” section): https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1730714/42969.

Comment: Set $n=0$ in $(6)$ from [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4101866).

Comment: This question appears to have been asked at least 12 times before here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:
$$
\int (x+1)^ndx=\sum_{k=0}^n\frac {x^{k+1}}{k+1}\binom nk +C
$$

Comment: This has been asked and answered several times already.

Comment: @MartinR This may be true. Yet it is almost impossible to tell on mobile.

Comment: I agree that mobile device experience may not be as good as a desktop/laptop experience, but I think we can use raw query in approach0 with desktop mode option available in many browsers.